# How can I push new values to a JavaScript object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object-literal

I have an object with a property that contains an array, I was wondering what the best way of inserting into that array, this is the object:

```
const object1 = 
  {"users": [{"username":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","id":"john_2011221"}, 
  {"username":"steve","email":"steve@gmail.com","id":"steve_201193841"}]};
```

I want  to make the object like this:

```
const object1 = 
      {"users": [{"username":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","id":"john_2011221"}, 
      {"username":"steve","email":"steve@gmail.com","id":"steve_201193841"}
      {"username":"Emily","email":"emily@gmail.com","id":"emily_20119567"}]};
```

Comment: `object1.users.push(newObject)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access the array inside the Object using object1["users"]. Then you can simply push your  new object into this array like this

```
const object1 = 
  {"users": [{"username":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","id":"john_2011221"}, 
  {"username":"steve","email":"steve@gmail.com","id":"steve_201193841"}]};

object1["users"].push({"username":"Emily","email":"emily@gmail.com","id":"emily_20119567"})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```js
object1.users.push({"username":"Emily","email":"emily@gmail.com","id":"emily_20119567"});
```